# AttributeError: 'REST' object has no attribute 'get_bars' (Alpaca trade API + Tensorflow)

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, alpacajs

This is my first post. At least 90%+ of all solutions I find in my infancy of programming have come from stackoverflow.com and I greatly appreciate you all. So much. I would like to give back at some point.

This is the error I've experienced where I cannot find a clear existing answer (perhaps I did not look hard enough. Or smartly enough).

I've recreated this gentleman's tutorial for a simple neural network for the stock market: https://hackernoon.com/forecasting-market-movements-using-tensorflow-fb73e614cd06

It was fully functional all the way to graphing its results in tensor board in my browser. I was proud. The next step was to use it as a platform to experiment with my own models.

Upon finding time to do so, I was disheartened to learn that somewhere along the way between then (maybe three weeks ago) and now, it has become non-functional. My guess is that it's a recent change in compatibility. Perhaps Python, Tensorflow, one of the pip installations I've made as a requirement.

After a very brief and helpful foray into the Python debugger (kudos to this gentleman: https://medium.com/@sourleangchhean/how-to-use-the-python-debugger-43a05a826f82)

I am getting the following error:

> c:\program files\python36\scripts\smarket\generate_dataset.py(49)()
>   -> returned_data = api.get_bars(
>   (Pdb)
>   AttributeError: 'REST' object has no attribute 'get_bars'

My troubleshooting skills are very good from engineering, but I have such a barely primordial understanding of computer science that those skills are relatively useless in computer science when I'm completely lost and cannot google a clear, contextually identical issue.

Any help greatly appreciated.

My current pip list is:

absl-py             0.6.1
alpaca-trade-api    0.24
astor               0.7.1
asyncio-nats-client 0.8.2
certifi             2018.11.29
chardet             3.0.4
gast                0.2.0
grpcio              1.17.1
h5py                2.9.0
idna                2.8
Keras-Applications  1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.5
Markdown            3.0.1
numpy               1.15.4
pandas              0.23.4
pip                 18.1
protobuf            3.6.1
python-dateutil     2.7.5
pytz                2018.7
requests            2.21.0
scikit-learn        0.20.2
scipy               1.2.0
setuptools          40.6.2
six                 1.12.0
sklearn             0.0
TA-Lib              0.4.17
tensorboard         1.12.1
tensorflow          1.12.0
termcolor           1.1.0
urllib3             1.24.1
websocket-client    0.54.0
websockets          7.0
Werkzeug            0.14.1
wheel               0.32.3

I am on Windows 10 running things from a basic cmd prompt run as administrator.

While my primary objective is to get through this error, I would also appreciate any constructive feedback on how to post these kinds of questions optimally here. I'm familiar with general engineering tickets and the concept of providing enough information to not require an intermediary request for information, but I am as green as it gets and would like to do things the way folks here would like them done.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

OK so looks like alpaca-trade-api package changed and the function get_bars is now get_barset and has different arguments. So, well, there it is.